# Styling SideCommand in codename one gives different results on IOS and Android

Tags: codenameone

I have a Side Menu style via CSS, on Android, desired result is achieved, but the same style breaks on IOS. Looks like I need to access the button inside the SideCommand to achieve this, however, I am stuck on this one. bellow is the CSS and the codename one code.

```css
SideCommand{
        background-color: #018de5;
        padding: 2mm;
        color: white;
        font-size: 3mm;
        border-width: 0mm;
        margin: 0.2mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;
    }
```

```
mainToolbar.addComponentToSideMenu(avatarBox);
    mainToolbar.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Home", FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, e -> {
        try {
            Home();
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            System.err.println("there is error");
        }
    });
    mainToolbar.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Credit", FontImage.MATERIAL_CREDIT_CARD, e -> {
        credithome.Home(this);
    });

    mainToolbar.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Clients", FontImage.MATERIAL_PEOPLE, e -> {
        clienthome.Home(this);
    });

    mainToolbar.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Accounting", FontImage.MATERIAL_BOOK, e -> {

        accountinghome.Home(this);
    });
```

The result on IOS is

[image: IOS Side Menu]

And android is fine

[image: Android Side Menu]

Comment: About the text under the iPhone notch, maybe this can be useful: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/safe-areas.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the border property too with an empty border as the default theme on iOS contains a border for the side command. It's something we'd like to fix in the future but for now it's there.

E.g.

```css
SideCommand{
  background-color: #018de5;
  padding: 2mm;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3mm;
  border: none;
  margin: 0.2mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Shai Almog, its worked straight away!!